# JavaScript: How to combine two different but pretty similar functions?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, arguments

Within those two functions;

- `url` path is changes.
- Depends on different `url` path; function `parameters` are changes.

I've tried several naming and usage to combine those functions but couldn't success! How can I use only a function? Thanks in advance.

```
function RunTestCases (name, foo, folder, host) {
    host = host || DynamicHost();
    folder = folder || 'FooFolderPath';

    return {
        title: name,
        hostPageUrl: host,
        url: folder + foo + '/'+ name +'.T.js'
    };
}

function RunMonkeyTestCase (name, folder, host) {
    host = host || DynamicHost();
    folder = folder || 'FooFolderPath';

    return {
        title: name,
        hostPageUrl: host,
        url: folder + name +'.T.js'
    };
}

//Usage of Functions;
RunTestCases('NameParam', 'FooParam');
RunMonkeyTestCase('NameParam', 'BarFolderPath', 'BarHostParam');

//For some specific usages.
RunTestCases('NameParam', 'FooParam', 'BarFolderPath', 'BarHostParam');
RunMonkeyTestCase('NameParam', null, 'FooHostParam');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to combine functions into one? Try it.

```js
function Test (title, foo, folder = 'FooFolderPath', hostPageUrl = DynamicHost()) {
  return {
    title,
    hostPageUrl,
    url: folder + (foo ? foo + '/' : '') + title + '.T.js'
  };
}

//Usage of Functions;
Test('NameParam', 'FooParam')
Test('NameParam', null, 'BarFolderPath', 'BarHostParam')
```

Comment: I just edit my post: I've forget to state `DynamicHost()` within `RunTestCase()` so I had to modify your usage; `host = host || DynamicHost();` and **worked well!**.

Comment: and why you've defined `FooFolderPath` for `folder` in params? I took it down in curly braces as; `folder = folder || `FooFolderPath` and works fine.

Comment: this is the default parameter in js. This should work like `folder = folder || FooFolderPatne` but more obvious

Comment: also I checked the option `function Test (name, foo, folder = 'FooFolderPath', host = DynamicHost()) {` and removed `host = host || DynamicHost()` **It looks like it works!** Could you check? This is a more elegant option

Comment: Exactly! worked and more elegant! But you missed state `title` on `url` config ;) So it should be: `url: folder + (foo ? foo + '/' : '') + title +'.T.js'`

Answer (score 1):

Keep the parameter order same in both functions and then at last add `foo` in parameter and then do something like below:

```js
function TestCase(name, folder, host, foo) {
  host = host || DynamicHost();
  folder = folder || 'FooFolderPath';
  let url;
  if (foo) {
    url = folder + foo + '/' + name + '.T.js';
  } else {
    url = folder + name + '.T.js'
  }

  return {
    title: name,
    hostPageUrl: host,
    url: url
  };

}

console.log(TestCase('NameParam', 'BarFolderPath', 'BarHostParam', 'FooParam'));

console.log(TestCase('NameParam', 'BarFolderPath', 'BarHostParam'));

console.log(TestCase('NameParam', 'FooParam', 'BarFolderPath', 'BarHostParam'));

console.log(TestCase('NameParam', 'FooHostParam'));
```

Comment: It would probably be a fair bit cleaner if you created the object first then added the url property conditionally. This gives you much less duplication and a single return statement. Also you missed their DynamicHost call

Comment: @Marie agree with you. Please have a look now

Comment: @VicJordan I've modified somethings to be able my aim and **it worked**; `host = host || DynamicHost();` and `if (foo !== undefined) {`. The unwanted thing is I'had to call function with `null` for some of usage :( as `RunTestCases('nameparam', null, null, 'fooparam'))`. So can I avoid to use `null` somehow?

Comment: @VicJordan I just edit my post: I've forget to state `DynamicHost()` within `RunTestCase()`

Comment: @NuriEngin no need to pass `null`. Please check my updated answer. Last case is failing because it is looking for `DynamicHost()` function otherwise it will also work if `DynamicHost()` is present in code.

Comment: @VicJordan What if I want to use the default folder and host? Then you have to write: `TestCase('NameParam', null, null, 'FooParam')`

Comment: Dear @VicJordan as I told your suggestion works fine but the answer I accepted is suits more to me be cause of `foo` param. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `foo` parameter is the distincted one.. I would use that, but you need to change the params order :

```
function RunTestCases (name, folder, host,foo) 
  {
  host = host || (foo? 'FooHostParam' : DynamicHost()) ;
  folder = folder || foo? 'FooFolderPath' : 'BarFolderPath')
  const url = (foo? (folder + foo + '/' + name +'.T.js') : (folder + name +'.T.js'));
  return {
      title: name,
      hostPageUrl: host,
     url
  };
}
```

Comment: in a question there is such a function call
: `RunTestCases('NameParam', 'FooParam')` With your code it will be like this: `RunTestCases('NameParam', null, null,  'FooParam')` but second variant is ok: RunTestCases ('NameParam', 'BarFolderPath', 'BarHostParam')

Comment: As I said, "you need to change the params order" , OP need to make changes to make this work . Same goes for every other possible answer . @ИльяЗеленько

Answer (score 0):

```
function RunTest (name, folder, host, foo) {
    host = host || (foo ? DynamicHost() : 'FooHostParam');
    folder = folder || 'FooFolderPath';

    returnVal = {
        title: name,
        hostPageUrl: host,
    };

    returnVal.url = foo ? folder + name +'.T.js' : folder + foo + '/'+ name +'.T.js';

    return returnVal;
}
```

Comment: You could probably augment folder before the url assignment so you dont have to have that logic in the set. It should save you duplicating the extension string.

Comment: You could modify folders value before the assignment, e.g. `if (!foo) folder = folder + foo + '/';` then just set url e.g. `returnVal.url = folder + name +'.T.js';`

Comment: isn't your ternary condition mixed ?